# mod_rewrite for sef enabled joomla site

Tags: mod-rewrite, joomla

my site is sef enabled and done in joomla.

what i need is a rewrite rule so

http://www.testsite.com/fr/corporate/news   points to  http://www.testsite.com/corporate/news/?lang=fr

i tried few url rewrite rules but it generates 404 error category not found page. i believe it looks for thr fr folder or a category called fr.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need it to work regardless of what is after `/fr`? You could try something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/fr/(.*) /$1\?lang=fr [R=301,L]
```

Comment: that works fine with r=301. but that will change the url. in other words its redirect------what i want is rewrite so the url stays the same

Comment: i have a rule which is<br/>

RewriteRule ^/([a-z][a-z])/(.*) /$2/?lang=$1 [R=301,L]<br/>

but this changes the value in the address bar. without r=301 it doesn't work at all

Comment: Hmm... maybe if you add the domain name to second argument: `RewriteRule ^/fr/(.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1\?lang=fr`  Honestly, I've only ever used Rewrites with R=301 to keep nice canonical URLs with the search engines.

Comment: that will yield the same results. what i want is rewrite that is without changing what is in the address bar